# How to set up the link for the paginated files in the Get Rows(V2) Logic App connector and pass it via Azure API call?

Tags: pagination, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, response-headers

I have created a Logic App and doing the pagination of the result retrieved by Get Rows(V2) connector. The threshold is set to 1500 and it is working fine. The test case file has 4484 records and the Until loop in the Logic App is iterating 3 times (1500, 1500 anf 1484), Now, i am trying to figure out how I can set up the link for these 3 paginated outputs so that they can be retrieved via the Azure API call.

[image: Logic App flow]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC36S.png)

I am calling this logic app through API but it giving the last result as the output. How can I set up the pages and links for them so that I can call the links and retreive all the records in 3 calls.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can provide the output of your `Get rows (V2)` action (no need to dump the whole huge output - just the beginning and the end of it, remove the middle), it will help providing you with an answer without actually replicating the whole flow.

Comment: @10p, the begining of the Get rows output is
{
  "body": {
    "value": [
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId":

and the end is 
 }
    ]
  }
}

there is no mention of odata.nextlink in any of the page. How can I generate that in the JSON output pages?